# how to get "xyz" text from span, I tried css but protractor did not identify it

Tags: protractor

```
<div>
<span tabindex="0" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:28pt;">xyz</span>
</div>
```

how to get "xyz" text from span, I tried css but protractor did not identify it

Comment: Failed: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector",
"selector":"#rt_NS_ > tbody > tr > td > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) >
td > span"}

Comment: http://www.cheetyr.com/css-selectors

Answer (score 1):

First of all your selector should look like:
`div > span`

You don't have `[...] > td > span`.

And then [.getText()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) on that element.